# Get the total number of master rows and grouped rows in a DevExpress GridControl

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916755/how-to-find-the-number-of-expanded-collapsed-master-rows-and-grouped-rows-in-a-d/8941619#8941619) I posted I found out how to keep track of the currently expanded grouped rows by using 2 events:

```
 - gridview.GroupRowExpanded
 - gridview.GroupRowCollapsed
```

where I increase or decrement an integer that keeps track of how many group rows are currently expanded. I am now tackling the problem of what to do if the user expands or collapses all of the group rows. I currently know when this is done by checking the `e.RowHandle`.

I was wondering if there is a way to find the total number of groups rows currently in the GridView (something like rowcount for normal rows) so I know how many to set the tracking integer to.

For Example:

- If my current count is 2 and the total number of groups are 15 then when the Expand All is fired the current count is set to 15 rather than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every detail when expanded is its own view.  So to get the master row count, you can use a count of the rows in the MainView property like:

```
GridControl1.MainView.RowCount
```

To get the number of group rows:

```
    Dim Handle As Integer = -1  'group rows have negative row handles
    Do Until GridView1.GetRow(Handle) Is Nothing
        Handle -= 1
    Loop
    Dim count As Integer = Math.Abs(Handle + 1) 'number of group rows
```

Alternately, you could use your datasource & linq something like:

```
    Dim count As Integer = (From item As Class1 In List Group By item.Something Into AsEnumerable()).count
```

but as far as I am aware there is no direct property for that one.

Comment: Thanks but the GridView1.GroupCount gives me '1' as a result no matter how many group rows are expanded because I have it grouped by only one column. I want the number of group rows and not the number of columns that the GridView is grouped by.